# How to make upload folder writeable, proper permissions on upload folder

Tags: server, apache2, webserver

`For my own reference.`

I'm having trouble finding the correct permissions for running a web site on my ubuntu machine. I'm confused whether to put 777/755 to whole directory of my site or webroot `public_html` in my home folder.

my username is arehman and my webserver user is www-data

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit
Apache2 php 7.1

**EDIT**

I have symlink to `/var/html/www/project_1` and the project is in `home/user/public_html/project_1`.  I have given 775 to the `project/uploads` folder and now files gets uploaded; but now every file is owned by www-data user:group and I can't edit the files if needed. Only way is to copy them, edit, and paste back in uploads folder.

Is there a way to make uploaded files have write access for my user?

Comment: Since it is a website I feel 755 is enough.777 means you are giving read, write and execute permission for user,group and others. For a website I feel only the user require all three permission so giving 755 is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the `777` or `755` is broken down like this:

Each of the numbers represents the privileges that are given to a particular group of people.  The first number represents the privileges given to *user* (system user), the second represents privileges given to *group* (system group), and the third is for *others* (anyone else trying to access the file).

Breaking down into the individual number, each value begins at 0 (no privileges) and adds `4` for executing privileges, `2` for writing privileges, and `1` for reading privileges.  Thus, `7` means executing, writing, and reading privileges (`4 + 2 + 1`), while `5` means executing and reading privileges (`4 + 1`).

For a website, the system user must have all write privileges (along with read and execute), hence the first number must be a `7`.  For group and others, only reading and executing privileges is necessary, hence the second and third numbers should be `5`, yielding `755` as the correct privileges for your public_html folder.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have edited my question please guide a bit more.